# taking variable from another class

Tags: java, android

I have to spinners, and when I start my app, the PHP only returns values of spinner's first choice.
First code is part of one class (IzboraGrada.java)

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
        spinner1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        str_grad=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        str_predmet=spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent i=new Intent (v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            url = "http://192.168.1.102/test/spinner.php";
            url=url+"?grad="+str_grad+"&predmet="+str_predmet;
            i.putExtra("URL",url);

            startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

And the second code is part of MainActivity.class that was in intent.

```
private void initView() {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

        String url = "http://192.168.1.102/test/spinner.php";

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            url = extras.getString("URL");
        }         
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }
```

I presume that's because str_grad and str_predmet are not defined in second class. But If I put str_grad and str_predmet in second class, they are can't be resolved as type.Any ideas what to do?

Comment: If you think the problem is with your PHP, then please add some PHP code.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's not PHP, cause PHP is working fine, when I start it from localhost. I just tagged PHP because of url, nothing else.

Comment: Ah, I see the tagging has been updated already.

Comment: When is `addListenerOnButton()` called?

Comment: It's unclear, could you elaborate on what you are trying to achive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are calling this method at the beginning, before an item is selected, so I think the problem is that you are setting the values for `str_grad` and `str_predmet` when they are first set so the selected item is the default item. Those are getter functions not listeners.

You need to move those lines inside the `onClick()` or use `onItemSelected()` on your `Spinners` to set those variable values

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    spinner1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

       str_grad=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();    // move these lines here
       str_predmet=spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Intent i=new Intent (v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        url = "http://192.168.1.102/test/spinner.php";
        url=url+"?grad="+str_grad+"&predmet="+str_predmet;
        i.putExtra("URL",url);

        startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

If I understand your problem correctly, that should solve your problem.

Comment: U are genius :) I didn't see that at all... I spent a whole day looking for a mistake somewhere else. Tnx a lot.